# Finding Jacobian $J_f$ of a map $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x,y)=\begin{bmatrix}
2+3xyz\\ 
2x^2+4y^2\\ 
5xz\\ 
3y^2+z^4
\end{bmatrix}$

- Find $J_f$.
- Find $\det J_f$.
- Is $f$ invertible at any point in $\Bbb R^4$?

**My try:**

We have the following, $ f_1 = 2 + 3xyz, f_2 = 2x ^ 2 + 4y ^ 4, f_3 = 5xz, f_4 = 3y ^ 2 + z ^ 4 $. Then,
$$ J_f (x, y) =\begin{bmatrix}
3yz & 3xz\\ 
4x& 16y^3\\ 
5z &0\\ 
0 & 6y
\end{bmatrix}.$$

But that is not a square matrix, so its determinant cannot be calculated, so the inverse function theorem cannot be applied. So we cannot know if it is invertible at any point in $ \Bbb R ^ 4 $. Is my reasoning okay?

Comment: Is $z$ a fixed constant?

Comment: Yes, the exercise does not say anything about $ z $. So, it is constant. @podiki

Comment: If it is really a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^4$ then yes, $J$ will be a $4\times 2$ matrix and cannot have a determinant or be invertible.

Comment: Maybe $f:\mathbb{R}^{2}\to \mathbb{R}^{2}$? Are you sure about your question?

Comment: Most likely, it is a trick question (parts 2 and 3).

Comment: There I have the image of how you say the question.  I can append it to see if I'm wrong.